# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type of model object

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, postman

I am trying to hit a service using postman by providing required request in JSON format :

```
 {
    "baseParam": {
        "userId": "u1234"
    },
    "resource": {
        "name": "resource"
    }
}
```

along with a multipart file as shown in the below postman screen

[Postman screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7youI.jpg)

But I am getting the error :

**'Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'SampleRequestObject'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type'**

**Controller**

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/sample/resource", 
   produces = "application/json")
   @ResponseBody
   public final ResponseObject sampleResource(@RequestParam("request") final 
   SampleRequestObject requestObject,@RequestParam("file") final 
   MultipartFile file,BindingResult result ) throws IOException {

   String success = “SUCCESS”;
   requestObject.setFile(file);
   String id=sampleService.sampleResourceService(resourceObject);   
   //sampleService Object has been autowired earlier in controller              
    return  success;                                                                                                       


    }  
    }
```

**SampleRequestObject – Model class**

```
    public class SampleRequestObject extends SampleMainObject {

    @NotNull
    @IsValid(baseParam = { "userId"})
    private BaseParam baseParam;

    @NotNull    
    private SampleResource resource;   // ANOTHER OBJECT OF SAMPLE RESOURCE 
                                          CLASS
    private MultipartFile file;

    public SampleResource getResource() {
    return resource;
    }

    public void setResource(SampleResource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override

    public Param getBaseParam() {

    return baseParam;
    }

    public final void setBaseParam(final BaseParam baseParam) {
    this.baseParam = baseParam;
    }

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
    }   
    }
```

**Function in SampleServiceImpl.class  (SampleService Implemetation)**

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public final String sampleResourceService( SampleRequestObject 
    requestObject) {throws IOException
    String Id=null;

    try
    {

    MainResourceObject resourceObject = new MainResourceObject();
    resourceObject.setActualName(requestObject.getFile()
    .getOriginalFilename());
    resourceObject.setName(requestObject.getResource().getName()); );   
        .
        .
        .
        .  
        .
        .
        .
        .  

        .  
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Service Execution failed",e);
    }
    }
```

**I also tried giving @ModelAttribute instead of @RequestParam. Then, it was possible to enter the controller as well as service, but all values of requestObject (in the controller) are being populated as null values. Hence, it throws NullPointeException from within the service implementation.**

**Please provide a solution.**

Comment: @benjaminc ... can you pls clarify wats wrong with json?

Comment: try changing `RequestParam` to `@RequestBody`

Comment: @benjamin c, thank you - that solved my similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
public final ResponseObject sampleResource(SampleRequestObject request,
       @RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile file,
       BindingResult result ) throws IOException {
...
```

I have just remove the `@RequestParam` and changed variable as `request`

Comment: I want ot take a request from Postman to the Controller. Tried your solution. But, didn't work.